# LinuxMint Boots into a Black Screen on an iMac

Tags: linux-mint, boot, apple

I've installed LinuxMint on an iMac(mid 2010) via a custom made USB installer I made. The installation process went fine. No errors. However, afterwards, when it boots, it displays nothing but a black screen.

First, I thought it was an installation issue; so, I installed it one more time. Same thing. Upon my research on the web, I've found it to clearly be a graphics driver problem. Specifically, a Radeon driver. This iMac of mine has a ATI Radeon HD 4670. Plus, on the second install, I chose the automatic login option and I can hear the boot sound when I power the iMac on and the OS launches even though there is a black screen.

On the web, people keep talking about going to GRUB and adding a `nomodeset`, `nvidia.modeset=0`, `nouveau.modeset=0` or `radeon.modeset=0` options. I did this via the USB installer's GRUB but I guess it only makes a difference for the installer and not the OS to be installed. I haven't applied the Nvidia options since my graphics card is an Radeon. With or without `nomodeset` and the radeon option, the installer works fine but the outcome is always the same: LinuxMint installs fine and boots but a black screen.

So, at this point, I can make the installer work and install the OS. Plus, I can hear the boot sound afterwards and I can see the OS files if I boot from the USB again and check the drive.

I've also tried Ubuntu. The exact issue occured again. I've also tried Fedora. I couldn't even get to the installation procedure. Keeps showing me a black screen when I select the install option. Since this is an iMac and not a typical PC with a regular BIOS interface, what are my options to sort this issue out? Can I make it work with LinuxMint? Perhaps I should switch to a whole different distribution? Or something completely different?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue. It was about adding `nomodeset` as I explained in the question. The problem was I was adding it in the wrong place.

When the installation finishes and your booting your machine(with a cable connected keyboard):

- press `e` during boot after you hear the classic macOS start-up chime,
- This will be the GRUB of the installed system,
- place `nomodeset` into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`,
- continue the boot by pressing `F10`.

This will make it work for the current boot. If you want to make it stick:

- edit `/etc/default/grub`,
- add `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`,
- save the file,
- execute `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` (the path here is liable to change).

The above procedure will disable your graphics card which will degrade your performance. However, you've a working system now that you can use to make your graphics card work. For instance, in my case, even though my graphics card is supported, I get a black screen if I enable it. There is a discussion [here](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/amd/-/issues/1958) that goes into it.